# function to remove class of a selected item using jquery

Tags: jquery

Look to this code and see if you guys can help me with.

HTML

```
<div class="images_list">
  <ul>
    <li class="border" title="content_1"><img src="http://localhost/FreeDownload/admin/upload/923411_481490901920862_1216973581_n.jpg" width="150" /><span></span></li>
    <li class="border" title="content_2"><img src="http://localhost/FreeDownload/admin/upload/923411_481490901920862_1216973581_n.jpg" width="150" /><span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.images_list li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.images_list li span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 128px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(../upload/check.png);
}
.images_list li span:hover {
    background: url(../upload/uncheck.png);
}
.images_list li.border {
    border: 6px solid #D8D8D8;
}
.images_list li.selected {
    border: 6px solid #4F8FDF;
    position: relative;
}
.images_list li.selected span {
    display: block;
}
.img_info {
    margin-top: 170px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.images_list li').click(function() {
  $('.images_list .selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
  $("#"+clicked).removeClass("hidden").siblings().addClass("hidden");
});
```

When the checkmark is hovered the icon changes to a minus icon to remove the selected state. I tried everything that i know but no success.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjFjR/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on span, here click will bubble up to the parent and select the element again. Try:

```
$('.images_list li span').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent("li").removeClass('selected');
    alert("remove class .selected");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tjFjR/6/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

When you click the span, you can use the same method as in the list click handler to remove the class:

```
$('.images_list .selected').removeClass('selected');
```

However, the click will then bubble up to the parent and select the element again, unless you use `stopPropagation` to keep it from bubbling:

```
$('.images_list li span').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.images_list .selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```